# Forge Viewer, raster images

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is possible to directly load a raster image (PNG, JPG, TIFF) to Forge Viewer?

I see the **Autodesk.PDF** add-in that can load PDF, I cant find any **Autodesk.IMAGE** add-in...
Otherwise I need to prior convert Image into PDF and than load it through **Autodesk.PDF**.

Answer (score 1):

The Autodesk Forge Viewer is based on Three.js - therefore you can use the Three.js API to load an image/texture, there is no need of a Viewer extension for that.

However it depends what you want to do. In case you just want to load an image in the scene, that code is enough.

```js
const texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "thumbnail256.png" );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map : texture });
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5, 20, 32);
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
const planeMesh.position.set(1, 2, 3);
NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addScene('custom-scene');
NOP_VIEWER.overlays.addMesh(planeMesh, 'custom-scene');
```

But if you want to apply the texture on an existing element in the loaded scene, you need to proceed like this:

```js
const texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "thumbnail256.png" );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map : texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
NOP_VIEWER.impl.matman().addMaterial('custom-material', material, true);
const model = NOP_VIEWER.model;
model.unconsolidate(); // If the model is consolidated, material changes won't have any effect
const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
const frags = model.getFragmentList();
const dbids = NOP_VIEWER.getSelection();
for (const dbid of dbids) {
  tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, (fragid) => {
    frags.setMaterial(fragid, material);
  });
}
NOP_VIEWER.impl.invalidate(true, true, false);
```

Note you may need to work out the texture uv, depending on the geometry.

Comment: thanks @cyrille, I have to add an image in the scene, not texture over other elements, so your first example could be my solution. I have found [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-models-forge-viewer) post on how load custom models on viewer, this is the right way to add texture? Do you have a complete example on how initialize viewer AND add texture with three.js? Thanks

Comment: @CristianBarzaghi, yes, Petr article is another way but very similar to what is above. A very different approach would be to create a glTF or OBJ file on the fly and load it into the scene. It really depends what you want to do. But if you do not want textures, I am not sure you can do it on a non 2d canvas :(